# Ziggeo API video will not play in Heroku

Tags: heroku

I have embedded a video into my site using the Ziggeo API. I am using Handlebars to populate the token to the ziggeo player:

```
<ziggeo id="zideo_player" ziggeo-width="560" ziggeo-height="315" ziggeo-playonclick="true" ziggeo-video={{this.token}}>
                </ziggeo>
```

I know that the token is getting there because I can see it in the inspector.

The weird thing is, when I go into the inspector and change from ziggeo to ziggeoplayer, the video will show, but when I push those changes to Heroku, it again doesn't show.

It's as if the player is loading before the token is received and only by changing the name can I re-send the token.

Answer (score 0):

v1 and v2 should both work on Heroku.

Benjamin, can you try replacing that HTML embedding code with JS code, which could then be delayed if really needed.

For example of same code in JS:

```js
    <script>
        //ZiggeoAPI will work only with v1-rXY/ziggeo.js v2- will require v2 app to be created and code would look just a bit different
        ZiggeoApi.Events.on("system_ready", function() {
            var player = new ZiggeoApi.V2.Player({
                element: document.getElementById("your_element_ID"),
                attrs: {
                    width: 560,
                    height: 315,
                    theme: "modern",
                    themecolor: "red",
                    playonclick: true,
                    video: "{{this.token}}"
                }
            });

            player.activate();
        });
    </script>
```

This would only fire once the Ziggeo system is loaded and ready. This means that it fires after the DOM is ready and page loaded so it should be before the `{{this.video}}` is available.

Comment: Thank you, but that didn't work either. The only thing that worked was appending the video in a separate .js file so that it loaded after the DOM was done. The problem was async as the DOM was loading before it had time to send and receive the information to Ziggeo.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be an asynch (asynchronization) issue. The video was trying to load before it could send and receive information from Ziggeo's API. To solve this, I used a separate js file and then appended the video information after the document loaded.

After some more thought, I might have also been able to fix this by placing the Ziggeo API information at the bottom of the body in the index.handlebars file instead of in the head. I didn't have a chance to try this since the above trick worked, but it would probably look cleaner if it did.